# Privacy setting to hide Facebook account from Facebook search not available

Tags: facebook, privacy, facebook-privacy, facebook-account, facebook-search

Facebook no longer allows a user to hide their account from a Facebook search, from what I can tell.  They allow a user to hide their account from outside of Facebook, but not within.  I've tested the privacy settings with two accounts, by doing a search from my other account, but got nothing to work.  If someone knows how to do this or if Facebook is working on a fix, please answer this question.

Looks like Facebook used to have another option of "Friends" under this setting, but now it is gone.

"Who can look up your profile by name or contact info?"

Options are:

- Everyone
- Friends of Friends
- Friends (now gone)

Comment: Help article about questions marked as "This questions already has an answer here:" -> [Why are some questions marked as duplicate?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/duplicates)

Comment: Please re-open.  My question still holds water.  The other post is for general privacy.  I checked all of those settings.  This is not a duplicate.

Comment: From the previous link "If you see a question closed as a duplicate but don't agree that it truly is a duplicate, **edit it to highlight the differences**,..."